# Is this a brussels sprout plant?

Tags: identification, vegetables, flowers, brassicas

I'm in North Carolina and a couple of these plants just sprouted in my garden. It is currently about 3 feet tall after at most a month of growing.

Because of the leaves my intuition is these are brussels sprouts.

*Click on pictures for closer view.*

[image: flowers]
[image: leaves]

Comment: I get more of a broccoli vibe from those leaves. But something in that family, yes

Comment: The small white butterfly is very adept at identifying brassicas, and will lay her eggs on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd concur that its a brassica of some sort, present from the birds I expect.